# Jquery UI, Razor and MVC: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-dialog

Attempting to get a Jquery UI dialog to confirm (OK, Cancel) a call to a delete operation (DeleteTestUser). My jquery ui dialog is coming up on click. The cancel button works as expected but OK is not.

The error (Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Invocation) is what Chrome is showing in the console when I click OK. This is probably not surprising since it doesn't know what testUser.TestUserId is...

How do I ultimately pass that value along from client to server? The delete operation from HomeController.cs otherwise does work without the confirmation dialog. I need to get OK to call that. I feel like I am close but not sure how to form the Url.Action post in Javascript.

I'm pretty sure the problematic line is the post in _layout.cshtml

_layout.cshtml

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#dialog-modal').dialog(
            {
                title: 'Test User',
                draggable: false,
                resizeable: false,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'OK': function() {
                        $.post("@Url.Action("DeleteTestUser", "Home")",
                            { id: $('testUser.TestUserId') });
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }

                }
            });

        $('#confirm-delete').click(function () {
            $('#dialog-modal').dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public ActionResult DeleteTestUser(int id)
    {
        this.testUserBusinessLogic.DeleteTestUser(id);
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

index.cshtml

```
    @foreach (var testUser in this.Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@testUser.FirstName</td>
            <td>@testUser.LastName</td>
            <td>@testUser.EmailAddress</td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("TestUser", "Home",
                        new {id = testUser.TestUserId})">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg text-primary"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="confirm-delete" >
                    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg text-primary"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: What is your script to open the dialog (you need to pass your `id` value there).And you have invalid html because of the duplicate `id="confirm-delete"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke the function $('#confirm-delete').click opens the dialog. The dialog is opening fine. Cancel works, OK does not...

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't see a duplicate id tag of confirm-delete. I can change the signature of the #confirm-delete click function to take the id value, but not sure how to pass it.

Comment: You have multiple `id="confirm-delete"` in the `<a>` element :) Give me 5 min and I'll add an answer.

Comment: I never did see id="confirm-delete" listed twice anywhere...and I don't understand why one would name the class value that, something that doesn't exist.

It does work however. Just need to figure out how to then redirect back to index after the delete.

Comment: It created once for every iteration of your `@foreach (var testUser in this.Model)` loop :)

Comment: I see that now, makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code that generates your link to both remove the duplicate id attribute (use a class name instead) and add a `data-` attribute to store the value of `TestUserId`

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="confirm-delete" data-id="@testUser.TestUserId">
        <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg text-primary"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

In the script, you can then retrieve the value and assign it to a `data-` attribute of the dialog before calling `open`

```
$('.confirm-delete').click(function () { // modify selector
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#dialog-modal').data('id', id).dialog("open");
});
```

and retrieve it when you click the OK button

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog(
    ....
    buttons: {
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'OK': function() {
            $.post('@Url.Action("DeleteTestUser", "Home")', { id: $('#dialog-modal').data('id') });
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think I see now, you're using the class attribute as a stand in to call the dialog. Seems unconventional to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: What is wrong is that you have duplicate `id` attributes, which is invalid html, and you always use a class name for cases like this :). As a side note, you probably use `{ id: $(this).data('id') }` in the `$.post()` but could not test it to be sure

Comment: Duplicate because of the Foreach you mean?